# Input after Textarea displays odd in different browsers

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, internet-explorer, firefox

I've noticed that in a simple HTML form such as below, the input after the textarea is inconsistent across browsers. I'm wondering if there is some CSS that will even this out? (notice the padding below the textarea in Chrome, Firefox)

```
<textarea></textarea><input type="text">
```

[image: Chrome,Firefox,IE screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

`<textarea style="vertical-align:bottom">`

This works for Chrome, not sure about the others...

**JSFiddle** https://jsfiddle.net/s83x26ej/

Comment: Remember that the default is baseline, which is why this is happening in the first place.